# output with shape [64, 1] doesn't match the broadcast shape [64, 2]

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I got above error when trying to pass weighted class to BCELoss (using pytorch). As you can see below. My model is  Resnet with Sigmoid. I guess the model expect one class value instead of two becouse its Sigmoid.
But which one of the value percentage, I should pass. The percentage of postive value (with 1) or negative (with 0)

```
class_weights2=[postive/(negtive+postive),negtive/(negtive+postive)]
print(class_weights2)
# [0.3135668226071564, 0.6864331773928436]
class_weights=torch.tensor(class_weights2,dtype=torch.float)
lossFunc= torch.nn.BCELoss(class_weights)
```

and this the model:

```
model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=False)

model.fc = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(
        in_features=2048,
        out_features=1
    ),
    torch.nn.Sigmoid()
)
```

Comment: I found this youtube very helpful to tackle imbalanced data https://youtu.be/4JFVhJyTZ44

Answer (score 1):

The weights passed to BCELoss are not class weights. They rescale the contribution of each element in the batch.
From the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.BCELoss.html):

> a manual rescaling weight given to the loss of each batch element. If
> given, has to be a Tensor of size nbatch.

Comment: Thank you. It seems I had misunderstanding. So then how do I fix the issue of having imbalance data. I thought its done through class weights.

Comment: I doubled check. I think its used when data imbalanced.

Comment: The BCELoss expects a weight for every entry in the output batch. If you look up which class this entry corresponds to, then you can assign the class label as weight for it. But that would mean constructing a new loss_fun for every batch. BCE is a simple function, you could just implement it yourself and multiply in the class weights.